# Python - How to unpack key with key,value pair?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

Anyone can help and explain how to unpack items from key with many key,value pair?

```
{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'result': [{'userid': '8', 'clock': '1644715846', 'action': '3', 'resourceid': '0'}], 'id': '1'}
```

I need transform 'result' to dictionary.

```
# Print type 'dict'
print(type(result2))

#Print type 'list'
print(type(result2['result']))

output = []


# Here i get error 

for key_value in result2['result']:
    key, value = key_value.split(': ', 1)
    if not output or key in output[-1]:
        output.append({})
    output[-1][key] = value

print(output)

"""
    key, value = key_value.split(': ', 1)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'
"""
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's a dictionary, not a string. Have you worked with lists and dicts before?

Comment: Everyone learn's, so do I. The problem may be trivial for some, and not for others;)

Answer (score 0):

As clearly `result2['result']` is a list but that list contains the dict which you want.

So to get that simply unpack this list and get the frst element;

`result2['result'][0]`

Answer (score 0):

`result2['result']` is a list of dicts.  To iterate over the list, you can do `for result in result2['result']`  To iterate over each resulting dict, you can do `for key, value in result.items()`.

```
result2 = {'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'result': [{'userid': '8', 'clock': '1644715846', 'action': '3', 'resourceid': '0'}], 'id': '1'}

output = [{}]
for result in result2['result']:
    for key, value in result.items():
        if key in output[-1]:
            output.append({})
        output[-1][key] = value

print(output)
# [{'userid': '8', 'clock': '1644715846', 'action': '3', 'resourceid': '0'}]
```

This code goes to a lot of trouble to iterate through each dictionary and accumulate a list of new dictionaries for the apparent purpose of combining dictionaries with disjoint sets of keys, but for this particular input, or any other input where each dictionary in `result` has the same keys, or any input where there's only one dictionary, there's no point in iterating over the dictionaries at all.  You could just as easily do:

```
output = result2['result']
print(output)
# [{'userid': '8', 'clock': '1644715846', 'action': '3', 'resourceid': '0'}]
```

to get the same exact output with none of the work.